# English slang for "bochar"

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, translation, spanish

I'm looking for some possible slangy words that are equivalent to this Ríoplatense term:

> **bochar**
>
> No aprobar a alguien tras haber rendido un examen o cursado una asignatura.
>
> "lo bocharon en literatura"

> **???**
>
> To fail a student after they had taken an exam or a course.
>
> (a short example, please)

The word is used mainly for focusing on the person who graded you, often with bad connotations, as if even you didn't have a chance to take the exam or course because the teacher didn't like you.

The references for that word are vague, I searched the word in all the dictionaries and only found something like '**flunk**', but I don't know if English speakers use it with the same connotation.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be in many dictionaries with this sense.  Please check a dictionary and include the translation.

Comment: @livresque I didn't understand what you're asking for. The references for that word are vague, I searched the word in all the dictionaries and only found something like 'flunk', but I don't know if english speakers use it with the same connotation

Comment: Perfect, you can [edit] that into your question.  Hope that clears it up a bit as to where you are confused.

Comment: When you translate "no apta" as "not apt" do you mean that they have taken the exam and scored badly in it or do you mean that the teacher has decided that the student is not ready for the exam and has prevented them from taking it? "Not apt" in English does not really convey either concept but is closer to the second one. I think that "apt" and "apta" are probably 'false friends' in English and Rioplatenese (which I assume is the dialect of Spanish spoken in the Rio Plate are of South America)

Comment: @BoldBen "no apt" means the first one. And now, I just think it's a bad definition of the term because "apta" and "apt" aren't false friends. I'll correct it now.

Comment: I changed it, but I don't know if "desaprobar" and "disapprove" are false friends or not in this context, please tell me that.

Comment: The term is still unclear: is this a case where someone should have passed the exam but was given a failing grade or barred from advancement because the teacher didn't like them? Or is this a case where the teacher was just so bad at teaching that the student had no chance of passing?

Comment: @Yorik Like the first case. It's like if even you didn't had a chance to perform the exam or course beacuse the teacher didn't like you

Comment: disapprove here is an outright English error. Please look up that word. apto and apt are false friends.

Comment: I did it. Why apto and apt are false friends? References where is stated they convey different meanings?

Comment: apto in Spanish means qualified to do something or being the right person to do something. Whereas in English, apt means likely: to probably [do something]. He is apt to leave early. I don't need a reference as I am fluent in both.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **to flunk** (in American slang) can mean "to deny a student a passing grade" (see [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/flunk)). It does tend to shift blame onto the teacher, though it isn't necessarily an insult towards them. An example usage would be:

> I tried my best on the essay, but my English teacher flunked me anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the "Ríoplatense" idiom.  If this is the same as the Spanish "fracasar," then "fail" would work well in English.  For example:

They *failed* in literature.

A colloquial term for "fail" might be "bomb", as in "he *bombed* the test," or as a two-word verb "bomb out", e.g. "they *bombed out* in math."

Comment: No, it means *to 'make' someone fail*. You might *bomb* an exam but it's correct to say that my teacher *bombed me* in an exam? Or that my teacher *bombed me out* in math?

Comment: No, the teacher cannot make you bomb out on the exam.  If you bomb the exam, it's your own fault.

Comment: In that case, the word "flunk" is more appropriate.  The teacher can flunk you.

Comment: "Bochar" is reminiscent of "botch" in English, but if I "botch" the exam, again it is my own fault.

Comment: Nice to know it, interesting despite not answering the question

Comment: @tac ¿No tendría nada que ver con el juego de bochas? Por desgracia, [el DRAE no menciona esta connotación ríoplatense (no digo jerga :) en los sentidos de *bochar*](https://dle.rae.es/bochar). Or is this more like [*dar (un) boche a alguién*](https://dle.rae.es/boche#2T1WWqf)? Definitely an interesting expression.

Comment: @tchrist The DRAE is quite poor about Ríoplatense lexicon, and it's more related to the second expression you mentioned. Yes, is interesting, I don't think however that the etymology comes from that expression because I never heard it.

Comment: "Fail" can be a transitive verb meaning to give a failing grade: "the teacher failed me at English".

Comment: @StuartF. That's true, but "fail" is standard language.  The OP was looking for English slang, and "flunk" is informal language which fits the usage, whereas "bomb out" does not.

Answer (score 1):

***No aprobar a alguien* tras haber rendido un examen o cursado una asignatura**.

"lo bocharon en literatura"

As a translator, and therefore, as my own reference:

**Not *pass someone* after they take an exam or a course**

**They flunked him in literature.**

Spanish reference:

**II.   1.  tr. Ar, Ur. Reprobar alguien a un alumno en un examen o asignatura. est.**

[Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española](https://www.asale.org/damer/bochar)

Translation:
II. 1. Transitive, Argentina, Uruguay To fail a student on an exam or in a course.

The slang term in English is to flunk (someone)

Please note:
The professor flunked me.
I flunked the exam.
flunk is the slang equivalent.